# Wo kommt der Ausdruck "Roter Retter" her?

Tags: idiom, etymology

Wiederholt habe ich jetzt den Ausdruck "Roter Retter" gesehen, sowohl in einer Kurzgeschichte als auch in Nachrichten (beispielsweise [hier](http://www.zeit.de/2004/13/FR_2fSPD)). Während ich in politischen Nachrichten noch nachvollziehen kann, dass man das irgendwie mit den linkspolitischen Farben assoziiert und da Wortspiele draus macht, ist mir das Auftauchen in der Kurzgeschichte völlig unklar.

Zusätzlich wirkt es auch in den Nachrichten so, als ob es ein feststehender Ausdruck sei. Google hilft mir leider nicht besonders weiter und das einzige, was mir selbst in den Sinn kommt, ist eine Verbindung zur Befreiung durch die Rote Armee, aber so ganz plausibel scheint mir das nicht.

Weiß jemand, ob es sich tatsächlich um eine mehr oder minder gebräuchliche Wendung handelt und wenn ja, wo sie herstammt? Danke schon einmal im Voraus.

Comment: Feuerwehr, vielleicht?

Answer (score 2):

Der Ausdruck "Roter Retter" ist mir so unbekannt.

In dem verlinkten Artikel bezieht sich das [rot als Symbol der Sozialisten/Kommunisten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rot#Politik), bzw. der [politischen Linken](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politische_Linke). D.h. im verlinkten Artikel sind die roten Retter Retter aus der SPD.

Laut Wikipedia sind [Farben](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parteisymbol) *Parteisymbole*.

Es steht für das Blut der Proletarier, die im Kampf gegen die Bourgeoisie ihr Leben ließen (siehe z.B. http://www.lerntippsammlung.de/Die-Farbe-Rot.html ). Das [Austria-Forum hat eine andere Erklärung](http://www.austria-lexikon.at/af/Community/Wissenswertes/Wissenschaft/Geschichte/Farbe_des_Sozialismus) für Rot als 'linke' Farbe.

Comment: Danke für die Hinweise. Dass die Farbe ein Parteisymbol darstellen kann, ist logisch. Trotzdem liegt für mich die Wahl der Überschrift bei dem Artikel nicht besonders nahe, wenn man damit nicht auf irgendetwas anspielt. Aber es scheint ja kein bekannter Ausdruck zu sein...